# Android - Strange fab elevation on Huawei device

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm getting strange elevation on Huawei 7" device, here is the code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_start"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_play_arrow_white_48dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/teal"
    app:useCompatPadding="true" />
```

and here is the result:

[image]

any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Give `wrap_content` to height and width of fab button;

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: it worked!! but how to increase the size of the fab?

Comment: You can try app:fabSize="mini"

Comment: I need the fab size to be 92dp and if I used wrap_content it will be too small.

Comment: Try to give diamension to fab    <dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">92dp</dimen>

Comment: I tried it before and it's not working, I tried this code in multiple devices and it looks fine, except for this Huawei.